# Can someone please explain what the following code does?

Tags: asp-classic

I'm currently working on a project that was written in classic asp. I've used this language some before but I'm rusty with it.

In that code I see the following function call:
`Result = SwapOEMPart(sItem)`

When I look at SwapOEMPart I see this:

```
function SwapOEMPart(oemPart)
  // Do a bunch of stuff
  oemPart = objRS("CCIPartNo") <-- this is the result of the stuff
end function
```

What does that do? Does it fill Result with the value of oemPart? Does it change the value of sItem (similar to a pass by reference)? Or perhaps it is something entirely different.

I'm familiar with returning data from asp functions by setting the function name equal to the value you want to return, but in this instance they are changing the value of the parameter they pass in and then just ending the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the code you have provided, I'm going to assume `objRS` is an `adodb.recordset`, if that is the case, `CCIPartNo` is a column in the recorset, all your code is doing is writing the value of that column into the `eomPart` variable - `eomPart` isnt referenced as `byref` in the function declaration but this is assumed as default if you're in vbscript (not .net)  so **it's almost as if the value of the column is being passed back into eomPart & because eomPart is a REFERENCE to the sItem value in your example, the actual value of sItem would change.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee478101%28VS.84%29.aspx